Name of animated film with a massive knot in a city/kingdom, whoever unties it is/becomes their king/leader?
My memory of this film has to be at least 8+ years old. I think that:

Kingdoms with epic sized armies are at war/something-important.
Probably 90's (or thereabouts) mainly hand drawn graphics.
The description claimed it was "dark anime," whatever that means.
I think there may have been some female nudity, possibly a evil queen.
One city/kingdom has a huge mess of a knot in the city square or public area, I think that whoever unties the knot is supposed to be their king/leader/ruler according to lore? Some guy/main-character takes his sword/blade and chops it.

I think I stopped watching because I didn't see it from the start, but forgot the name.

I think the knot mention in here is "Gordian knot" and originally the story connects with king Alexander but I don't know the name of this animated Film.

Are you sure it was a film, and not an episode from a series?

@SystemDown It is possible the film has sequels or prequels, although I doubt it. I don't think it is a series, I believe I saw it on an encore channel and the info labeled it dark anime. It came on late in the night, past midnight-1am.

Since what you describe is basically the Gordian Knot legend of Alexander the Great fame, I did a search for anime shows based on Alexander's story, and I found Reign: The Conqueror, which apparently also had a movie version. Here's a trailer for the movie version on YouTube.


This looks highly promising, I will look for the scene I mentioned and accept when I find it, thanks!
